# Adobe Acrobat PDF Sections

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, openxml, acrobat

I was looking in to Adobe acrobat and one of the features I noticed was that when you hit control + F there is a popup to find and replace text. Once you hit the replace button on the popup, all the text inside the entire PDF Document becomes split into small sections surrounded by a box. Even after I close out of the find and replace pop up, the sections remain. Is this a Adobe Acrobat feature or can this be done through other libraries.

I've been playing around with iTextSharp and have come close but not quite. I understand there are no words or phrases in pdfs but adobe has to be able to do it somehow. Is it possible to get this from the raw data or xml. I think if I can get answer to how adobe does identify the sections it will be really helpful. Does anyone have a idea to getting these?

I've also tried converting the pdf to word document manually through acrobat and using open xml to parse the text. The weird thing is, the word document contains headers and footers which weren't able to be identified by itextsharp. Does this mean it is being stored somewhere in the raw data at least?

Thank you ill appreciate it.

Comment: Please be aware that Adobe Acrobat is a pretty sophisticated tool. What its functionalities do, may require quite a lot of complex code. Furthermore it is a tool with a GUI, so if some functionality goes haywire for some internally weird pdf, the user immediately recognizes it and reverts the effect. IText, on the other hand, is usually used for automatic pdf processing, so anything gone wrong usually cannot easily be undone anymore when it is recognized eventually by some document receiver.

Comment: That been said, though, similar functionalities can be implemented on top of iText but you have to write the appropriate code...

Comment: @mkl Thank you for your fast responses and I will try to implement with iText.